# argument of type 'jquery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'element'

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I compile my TS file, I get an error as "*argument of type 'jquery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'element'*".

Why does this error occur?

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get DOM element from jQuery object:

```
    var $element: JQuery = $("<div/>");
    var element: Element = $element.get(0);
```